# Application of closed operator theory.

Tags: functional-analysis

Use the closed operator theory to show the following result:

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $C^1[0,1]$ such that the function series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ converges uniformly for a function $f$ in the interval $[0,1].$ If the series of functions $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f'_n$ converges uniformly in the interval $[0,1],$ show that $f \in C^1[0,1]$ and that
$$f'(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n}'(t), \quad \forall t \in[0,1].$$

Can I use the following Lemma to solve this exercise? If so, how do I define T?

Lemma (Closed operator). (Kreyszig's book) Let $T: X \to Y$ be a bounded linear operator with domain $D(T) \subset X,$ where X and Y are normed spaces. If $D(T)$ is a closed subset of $X,$ then $T$ is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using the usual norn $\|f\|_{\infty}+\|f'\|_{\infty}$ on $C^{1}[0,1]$.

Hint:Use the sequence $( \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} f_k,\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} f_k')$ in the graph of $T$. The graph is closed, by the Lemma.